# How do I stop collision jittering in a coordinate movement based system for pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm self teaching myself how to use pygame and I've got a problem where if I move my character to collide with the enemy rectangle it causes the player controlled rectangle to move inside the enemy rectangle This makes it impossible for me to move up and down and when I release the key my character is pushed away which makes my character jitter if done in repeated succession. I have shared the code below and would appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit 
pygame.init() 

Display = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
DisplayName = pygame.display.set_caption("SCP REDUCTION")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Character = pygame.Surface((80,150))
Character.fill("BlueViolet")

Enemy = pygame.Surface((80,150))
Enemy.fill("Red1")

PlayerRect = Character.get_rect(topleft  = (50,475))
EnemyRect = Enemy.get_rect(topleft = (400,400))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("key down")        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            print("key up")
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        print("W")
        PlayerRect.bottom -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        print("S")
        PlayerRect.bottom += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        print("D")
        PlayerRect.left += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        print("A")
        PlayerRect.left -= 5

    Display.blit(Character, PlayerRect)
    Display.blit(Enemy, EnemyRect)
    
    if PlayerRect.colliderect(EnemyRect):
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            print("collision")
            PlayerRect.bottom += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            print("collision")
            PlayerRect.bottom -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            print("collision")
            PlayerRect.left -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            print("collision")
            PlayerRect.left += 5
    
    pygame.display.update()
    Display.fill("black")
    clock.tick(60)
```